# Как внедрить R скрипт в WEB проект

Tags: r

Я обладаю навыками необходимыми для создания WEB-проекта и программирую на языке R в RStudio.

Как внедрить в WEB-проект скрипты из R?

Конкретно интересует, как сделать, чтобы графики которые я делаю в RStudio генерировались на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее оптимальным и производительным решением считаю `Rserve`, для которого есть клиенты под множество ЯП.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю вам надо смотреть в сторону либо [Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com) (если вы хотите создать приложение целиком на R), либо [Rapache](http://rapache.net) (позволяет обрабатывать на R http запросы и строить результирующую страницу)

Кажется, второй вариант вам более подойдет, если я правильно понял вопрос.